# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

I'm using the following configuration for Sprinc IOC container. 
My app-config.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



   <bean id="myDatasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bus_db" />
        <property name="username" value="sysadmin" />
        <property name="password" value="adminadmin" />
   </bean>

<!--    <context:property-placeholder location="src/main/java/com/bus/assets/dbinfo.properties" />  -->


   </beans>
```

My project sutructure is:

[image]

My Bean class that will be used for injection is:

```
    package com.bus.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.bus.model.Bus;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("busDAO")
public class BusDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate myJdbcTemplate;

    public List<Bus> getBusList(){
        return myJdbcTemplate.query("select * from bus.bus", 
                new RowMapper<Bus>() {

                    @Override
                    public Bus mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Bus bus = new Bus();
                        bus.setBrandName(rs.getString("brand_name"));
                        bus.setBusId(rs.getInt("bus_id"));
                        bus.setBusNumber(rs.getString("bus_number"));
                        bus.setModelNumber("model_number");
                        //bus.setProdDate(prodDate);
                        return bus;
                    }

        });
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getMyJdbcTemplate() {
        return myJdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMyJdbcTemplate(DataSource ds) {
        this.myJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

}
```

However, when I try to test Spring bean injection I'm getting the error that the bean named "busDAO" could not be found. I've also outputed into my Spring Tool Suite console the array of existing beans which is empty.

```
public class TestConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ApplicationContext appcon = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/app-config.xml");
    System.out.println("Bean names: " + Arrays.toString(appcon.getBeanNamesForType(BusDAO.class)));


    BusDAO myBusDAO =  appcon.getBean("busDAO", BusDAO.class);

    List<Bus> myBusList = myBusDAO.getBusList();

    for(Bus b: myBusList) {
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }

}
```

}

What I could do better in order to allow my Spring Bean context to find the missing bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done: added a property named private DataSource dataSource to busDAO

```
@Component("busDAO")
public class BusDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate myJdbcTemplate;
    private DataSource dataSource;
    .....
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
          this.myJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
       }
```

and after that configured the bean acordingly in xml configuration: `<bean id="busDAO" class="com.bus.dao.BusDAO"> <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> </bean>`

Answer (score 1):

- The problem here is there seems to be a confusion between @Component and @Bean.
- What you need to do is create another class, annotate it with @Configuration.
- In this class, you should create a function annotated with @Bean and this function should return your initiated Dao.
- I might add the code for it if required.

  @Configuration 
  public class DaoConfiguration{
      @Bean
      public BusDAO dao {
          return new BusDAO();
      }
  }

And you can use this bean using
@Autowired BusDAO busDao

I'm sorry for the badly formatted code :)

Comment: It's very likely that the class will not be discovered, as no component scan is taking place

Comment: We'll have to see his entire codebase to see whether he has declared componentscan annotation anywhere to confirm that I guess...

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add `context:component-scan` element to the `app-config.xml` or instantiate the bean manually:

```
<bean id="busDAO" class="com.bus.dao.BusDAO">
  <!-- specifics omitted as i am not that good with xml config -->
</bean>
```

The option to instantiate manually in an `@Configuration` annotated class will, again, require the `context:component-scan` element, or a bean definition of said class:

```
<bean id="myConfiguratioClass" class="com.bus.configuration.MyConfigClass" />
```

Comment: I've tried to add add a new bean in app-config.xml however the bean is initialized to null even if I have autowire declared in the setter method in order to be injected into datasource.

Comment: Which bean in initialized to null - the dataSource, the jdbcTemplate or the busDAO?

Comment: jdbcTemplate is  initializad to null and as a consequence busDAO

Comment: dataSource is not null

Comment: As there is a lot of information missing, I can only assume here, however it is most likely be useful to try the following:
* Do not create a new JdbcTemplate yourself, inject it directly. A working JdbcTemplate requires an explicit call to `afterPropertiesSet`
* Try to inject via Constructor

The `busDao` will not be `null` if there is a `DataSource` to inject - however it is possible that the `@Autowired` on the setter is not discovered due to missing `component scan`.
Remember, that you can declare a `bean ref` in the xml to pass an existing bean reference to a method

Comment: thank you for support. What I have done: added a property named  private DataSource dataSource to bus DAO and after that configured the bean acordingly in xml configuration:    <bean id="busDAO" class="com.bus.dao.BusDAO">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  </bean>